# Using multi-match query in a multi-field does not work

Tags: elasticsearch

Our system stores account in the following format: `acct:username@domain`
But for many searches we only need to username, so for the user created memos I've decided to make the user field a `multi_field` like this:

```
{
  'text': {
    'type': 'string'
  }
  'user': {
    'type': 'multi_field',
    'path': 'just_name',
    'fields': {
      'user': {
        'type': 'string',
        'index': 'analyzed',
        'analyzer': 'lower_keyword'
      },
      'username': {
        'type': 'string',
        'index': 'analyzed',
        'analyzer': 'username'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and other settings:

```
__settings__ = {
    'analysis': {
        'tokenizer': {
            'username': {
                'type': 'pattern',
                'group': 1,
                'pattern': '^acct:(.+)@.*$'
            }
        },
        'analyzer': {
            'lower_keyword': {
                'type': 'custom',
                'tokenizer': 'keyword',
                'filter': 'lowercase'
            },
            'username': {
                'tokenizer': 'username',
                'filter': 'lowercase'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I make a query for the username it works. I.e if I have the following user: `acct:testuser@testdomain`

and I make a query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "username": [
              "testuser"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "size": 50
}
```

It works (I know it can be done much easier but this is a system generated query).

But, I need to make searches which looks for a string in both the text and the username fields.
I've decided to use a `multi-match` query for this.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "operator": "and",
            "query": "testuser",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
              "text",
              "username"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "size": 50
}
```

Now the problem is, that this query does not work for the username field. It does for the text field, and for other fields if I include them, but does not bring back any result for the username field.

Can you help me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've forgotten that the username analyzer would also tokenize my searches for match/multi match queries. That way the string 'testuser' was analyzed and it generated zero token.

So the solution is to change the username's field mapping to:

```
'username': {
    'type': 'string',
    'index': 'analyzed',
    'index_analyzer': 'username',
    'search_analyzer': 'lower_keyword'
}
```

and now both queries are working.